# Delete image file right after compressing is complete. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a website which allow a user to upload some image on the server via upload form. When this image is uploaded, asp.net service should compress that particular image. Compressing an image already works great but I would like to delete an original image from server's disk when compressing is complete.

Please take a moment and look at my code below:

```
 if (fileUl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || fileUl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png") 
 {
    fileUl.SaveAs(fullPath);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullPath); 
    compressImage(destinationPath, image, 40);
     System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);

 } // nested if
```

If I try to run code above I'm getting

> *System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file [filepath] because it is being used by another process.*

I actually expect that because I think it's because, server is still compressing an image when next line of code wants to delete that image (I think this is it). So my question is:

How to wait for compressing to be complete and then run "delete" code?

Comment: You need to call its **Dispose method**. 

In general, the rule is that if an object implements the **IDisposable** interface, you should call its **Dispose** method as soon as you are finished with it. This helps to avoid memory leaks for objects that make use of unmanaged resources. The best way to do this is wrapping it in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullPath))
{
  //DO compression;
}
System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
```

Better do it all in compress function:

```
public void DoCompression(string destination, string fullPath, int ratio)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullPath))
    {
      //DO compression by defined compression ratio.
    }
}
```

The caller function may look like:

```
DoCompression(destinationPath, fullPath, 40);
DoCompression(destinationPath, fullPath, ??);

System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
```

Comment: Good that it helps :)

Comment: I already accepted your answer, but i just got another problem. Your code is working but what if I need to compress and create two (same) images but with different compression. Because I want to have one compressed image for thumbnails in my app, and another (highier quality) for actual picture. How would be the code then? Can you update your answer please :) ?

Comment: not a problem, using statement handles automatic dispose fo disposable object. I will update the code now

Comment: Now I'm getting: A generic error occurred in GDI+. System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException.

Comment: Ups, my bad. I was saving the other image in same folder with same name as original image. It works now. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

From [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx):

> The file remains locked until the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) is disposed.

Try:

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullPath); 
compressImage(destinationPath, image, 40);
image.Dispose(); //Release file lock
System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
```

or (slightly cleaner if an exception is thrown):

```
using(System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullPath))
{
    compressImage(destinationPath, image, 40);
}
System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing in `compressImage`. if you are using threads to compress the image then you are right. but I think different. You have to `Dispose` the `image` object.

Answer (score 0):

Several approaches

- Use sequential execution

  - Blocking compress image
  - Blocking delete image

  As others suggested make sure you free the resources correctly after each stage
- Use wait handles, such as [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)
- Implement a queueing producer-consumer, where producer enqueues an image to be processed, and consumer dequeues an item, compresses it and deletes original image. Producer and consumer are likely to be different processes.

I would probably go for the first approach as it is simple. Second approach is easy to implement, but it holds threads and degrades performance of web application. The third approach is useful if your web site is under heavy load.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a [Using statmement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure proper disposal of the image object.

```
if (fileUl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || fileUl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png") 
{
    fileUl.SaveAs(fullPath);
    using(System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fullPath))
    {
        compressImage(destinationPath, image, 40); 
    }
    System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
} // nested if
```